# ChromeDriver インストールする際、libX11、GConf2、fontconfigライブラリもインストールする理由は？

Tags: chromedriver

ChromeDriver インストールする際、libX11、GConf2、fontconfigライブラリもインストールする理由は何ですか？

[CentOS7上でSeleniumからGoogle Chromeのヘッドレスモードを利用する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/yuki-k/items/716bd05f087fc0f835bf)

上記ページの説明では "動作に必要なライブラリを入れる" とありますが、それぞれ何の動作に必要ですか？
Seleniumを使用せず、スクリーンキャプチャ取得するためだけにChromeDriver インストールしたいのですが、これらのライブラリは関係ありますか？

これらのライブラリを入れていない状態でもスクリーンキャプチャを取得できましたが、これらのライブラリを入れたらスクリーンキャプチャがより綺麗に取得できるのかと思い質問しました

環境
CentOS7

Comment: ChromeDriver が正常に動作しているという事は、利用しているホストに Google Chrome がインストールされていて、依存関係から既に libX11 などの shared library がインストール済みなのではないでしょうか。`ldd $(which chromedriver) | grep -i x11` などを実行してみると確認できるかと思います。

Comment: コマンド実行結果は「libX11.so.6 => /lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f2d8d3c5000)」でした。「which libX11」で見つからなかったので、インストールしていないと勘違いしました。※他ライブラリは見つかりませんでした

Comment: libX11 は各種 Linux distribution のデスクトップ環境(GNOMEやKDEなど)においては必須のライブラリですし、GConf2 は GNOME環境では必須かと思います。fontconfig も広く利用されています(Google Chrome も利用)。その記事を書かれた方が何か思い違いをしていたのかもしれません。

Comment: `which` は PATH の通ったディレクトリから実行権限の付いたコマンドを探すコマンドですから、ライブラリ (*.so) を探す用途には使えません。

Comment: @metropolis。この3ライブラリをインストールしているサイトは他にもあったので何だろう？ と思ったのですが……「https://qiita.com/yoshi0518/items/3b69ee59a377c58ff3fd」「https://worklog.be/archives/3422」「https://rooter.jp/web-crawling/setup-headless-chrome-centos/」

Comment: 想定される状況としては非デスクトップ(X Window Systemを利用していない)環境下で Chrome + chromdriver を動作させる場合ですかね。その場合は上記のライブラリはインストールされていないかもしれませんが、yum コマンドなどで Chrome をインストールする際に libX11 と fontconfig は依存関係から自動でインストールされる可能性が高いです。この記事「[Amazon LinuxでSelenium環境を最短で構築する](https://qiita.com/onorioriori/items/4fa271daa3621e8f6fd9)」を読むと、「ChromeDriverを実行する時に GConf2 がないと動きません」と書かれているのですが、少なくとも ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36(2019-11-18) では不要です。当該の記事でインストールしているのは Google Chrome version 63/ChromDriver 2.34 なので、バージョンアップの過程で GConf2 は不要になったのかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど。常に必須というわけではなく、環境によっては「動作のために必要なケースも過去にはあった」という感じですね。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpm -qi <PACKAGE>` で Summary や Description の項目を見ればどんなパッケージなのかがある程度確認ができます。

Chrome はGUIのアプリなので、(ヘッドレスで動かすとしても) GUI関連の **共有ライブラリ** を入れているのだと思います。

> **libX11**
>   X.Org X11 libX11 ランタイムライブラリ
>
> **GConf2**
>   GConfは、ユーザー設定の保存に使用されるプロセス透過的な設定データベース API です。
>   プラグ可能なバックエンドやワークグループ管理のサポート機能があります。
>
> **fontconfig**
>   Fontconfig は、システム内でのフォントの位置検出とアプリケーションで指定された要求に応じて
>   それを選択するようにデザインされています。